# Shortcode not working when I output data from wpdb html table row

Tags: shortcode

So I created a custom page in dashboard with a tinyMCE editor that can save html in a table row that i created in wp db.

I am also able to output the html on a custom template page.
However the shortcodes I write in the tinyMCE (ex [phone]) will display as plain text and not the data it was supposed too.

I know outside the default content editor and in template page you will normally display the shortcode with

```
echo do_shortcode('[phone]');
```

but I cannot write this into the tinyMCE editor.

How can I get the shortcodes to work?

Best Regards
Shane Akira

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I didn't thought it would be that easy.

So when I am storing the html in a variable "$htmlContent" and echo the variable in my template I can just wrap the variable in the do_shortcode() function

```
echo do_shortcode($htmlContent);
```

Maybe this answer are useful for other with the same problem.